# Отправка почты в отдельном потоке

Tags: php

Проблема в том, что при отправки запроса - отправка почты, тормозит скрипт, при этом работает медленнее, чем нужно.
Можно ли ускорить этот процесс, без подключения подобно `pthreads` расширений?
Есть ли какой-то другой выход? Или все-же придется подключать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно реализовать некий рассыльщик, который будет дергать письма из БД.

Т.е. при отправке почты вы создаете запись в БД, но не отправляете почту.

Другой скрипт по крону, либо с бесконечным while опрашивает базу данных на наличие новых записей. Если появились записи, получаем их и отправляем почту.

Comment: Уже пройдено, забыл написать, что про крон и Sheduler не нужно, похоже и вправду проще подключить, чем настраивать, какие-то рассыльщики. К тому же - это надо не всегда, а ваше решение будет постоянно работать.